# What do $/ and $\ do?

Tags: arrays, perl, special-variables

I've found `$\ = $/` when I was investigating how to merge 2 arrays, but I don't understand this at all. An example with it:

```
use strict;
$\ = $/;

my @array1 = ("string1", "string2");
my @array2 = ("string3", "string4");

my @array = (@array1, @array2);

print for @array;
```

What do they mean?

Comment: Ref. [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$\` is the output record separator. Whatever it contains is appended to each `print` statement. `$/` is the input record separator, which has the default value of `\n` (newline). By setting the output record separator to newline, you don't have to add a newline to your print statements, making the statement:

```
print for @array;
```

..look much smoother, compared to

```
print "$_\n" for @array;
```

Note that if he had used `use 5.010;` instead of `$\ = $/;`, he could have used

```
say for @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the Perl documentation, or [another good write-up is here](http://www.kichwa.com/quik_ref/spec_variables.html).

`$/` is the input record separator, `$\` is the output record searator.  The link above has some helpful mnemonic devices for remembering these and all of the other special Perl variables.